# Scrapy: Maintain location cookie for redirects

Tags: python, scrapy, request

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import LowesspiderItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class LowesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lowes'

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=8654RM-42']

        for url in start_urls:
            yield Request(url, cookies={'sn':'2333'}) #Added cookie to bypass location req 

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.css('.grid-container')
        for product in items:
            item = LowesspiderItem()

        #get product price
            productPrice = product.css('.art-pd-price::text').get()
        #get lowesNum
            productLowesNum = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        #get SKU
            productSKU = product.css('.met-product-model::text').get()

            item["productLowesNum"] = productLowesNum
            item["productSKU"] = productSKU
            item["productPrice"] = productPrice


            yield item
```

Output:

```
{'productLowesNum': '1001440644',
 'productPrice': None,
 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}
```

Now, I'll have a list of SKU's so that's how I'm going to format `start_urls`, so,

```
start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=('some sku)']
```

This url would redirect me to this link: https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644

**That's handled by scrapy**

**Now the problem**

When I have:

```
start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=8654RM-42']
```

I get the SKU but not the price.

However when I use the actual URL in start_urls

```
start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644']
```

then my output is fine:

```
{'productLowesNum': '1001440644',
 'productPrice': '1,449.95',
 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}
```

So, I believe using a URL that has to be redirected causes for my scraper to not get the price for some reason, but I still get the SKU.

Here's my guess: I had to preset a location cookie because the Lowes website does not allow you to see the price unless the user gives them a zip code/ location. so I'd assume I would have to move or adjust `cookies={'sn':'2333'}` to make my program work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The main issue here is that some of your cookies which are set by the first request

> https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=8654RM-42

are carried forward to the request after the redirect which is

> https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644

These cookies are overriding the cookies set by you.

### Solution

You need to send explict cookies to each request and prevent the previous cookies from being added to the next request.

There is a setting in scrapy called [`dont_merge_cookies`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#std:reqmeta-dont_merge_cookies) which is used for this purpose. You need to set this setting in your request meta to prevent cookies from previous requests being appended to the next request.

Now you need to explicitly set the cookies in request header. Something like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=8654RM-42']

    for url in start_urls:
        yield Request(url, headers={'Cookie': 'sn=2333;'}, meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True})
```

Comment: okay thank you, Ill try this out tomorrow! So this makes it so when I go through the redirect, the location cookie that I set doesn't get overwritten by a blank location cookie right?

Comment: Since we are explicitly sending cookies with each request and not merging cookies from previous requests, so the redirect will not cause any issues.